# How would one resolve a machine's hostname in python without using socket,os,etc. modules?

Tags: python

Is it possible to resolve the machine name of a computer without using any modules?

Now, I know trying to do it without modules is a little redundant and complicated. I've only tried a little to do some using things like `uname` and all. I just wanted to know if something could be done without having to first `import socket`.

Comment: Why is it redundant? Its redundant to reinvent the wheel. Also not complicated to do `import socket` or `import platform`. They are both stdlib so you have them anyway

Comment: Why do you need to look it up without modules? what is your overall goal?

Answer (score -1):

which operating system? on various operating systems there is an environment variable called HOSTNAME

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv('HOSTNAME')
'my_host'
```

Comment: The operating system is Ubuntu, I think I may have most of the code I need now from an example given to my friend.